# Exception "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." when sending FCM notification from c# (ASP.NET) to an android application

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, firebase, notifications

I just started using FCM and Android (i.e. I'm new) and the android app receives notification fine if it is sent from firebase console but nothing from website (ASP.NET)

This is the server side code that I'm using to send FCM notification on an android app.

```
static void SendMessage()
{
    string serverKey = "key";

    try
    {
        var result = "-1";
        var webAddr = "https://xxxx/fcm/send";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + serverKey);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"**recievers key**\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!\",}}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***********http**********"+ex.Message);
    }
}
```

> exception: "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not
>   Allowed."

I got the code from [here](https://www.codeprojecI.com/Questions/1166151/Use-Csharp-FCM-for-android-push-notification). I have uploaded it on an IIS server and it didn't work.

Comment: I implemented Push Notifications for Android using PushSharp library not too long ago , That did not have any issue with web , https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp , Read GCM (FCM) portion , Hope this helps

Comment: @FrankenstineJoe Joe  I haven't used GCM and PushSharp at all and I assumed GCM was different from FCM?

Also this is android code, my android side works perfect but not when im trying to send a notification from my asp.net website